# Why does Material-UI and redux cause type incompatibility?

Tags: typescript, redux, material-ui

I have a typescript class component w/ material-ui & redux integrations. When I wrap material-ui with redux there is some confusion about the "inherited" or "merged" prop types. If I export only material-ui integrated or only redux integrated it compiles w/o issue. If I remove the props from `mapStateToProps` it compiles as well. Of note, This code compiled prior to recent package updates.

I've created a sandbox @ https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-worker-qtb12?file=/src/App.tsx, the code compiles there ~ but the linter displays the same error I get in my project.

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'JSXElementConstructor<Omit<{ classes: ClassNameMap<string>; } & { user: User | undefined; }, "theme" | "classes"> & StyledComponentProps<string>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<Matching<{ user: User | undefined; }, any>>'.
  Type '(props: Omit<{ classes: ClassNameMap<string>; } & { user: User | undefined; }, "theme" | "classes"> & StyledComponentProps<string>) => ReactElement<...> | null' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<Matching<{ user: User | undefined; }, any>>'.
    Type '(props: Omit<{ classes: ClassNameMap<string>; } & { user: User | undefined; }, "theme" | "classes"> & StyledComponentProps<string>) => ReactElement<...> | null' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<Matching<{ user: User | undefined; }, any>>'.
      Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
        Type 'PropsWithChildren<Matching<{ user: User | undefined; }, any>>' is not assignable to type 'Omit<{ classes: ClassNameMap<string>; } & { user: User | undefined; }, "theme" | "classes"> & StyledComponentProps<string>'.
          Property 'user' is missing in type 'PropsWithChildren<Matching<{ user: User | undefined; }, any>>' but required in type 'Omit<{ classes: ClassNameMap<string>; } & { user: User | undefined; }, "theme" | "classes">'.
```

Note `user: User | undefined` present on both sides of the equation.

Comment: I'm not to familiar with reacts class component syntax, but wouldn't swapping the order fix this issue? `export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(connector(App))`

Comment: Also, may i ask why you're using class components and connect instead of function components and hooks? I don't think you'd have this issue with function components and hooks. At least i haven't had these issues when using neither redux hooks nor material-ui hooks.

Comment: @Olian04 totally agree, trying not to refactor the numerous pre-existing files; I think you solved this ‍♂️, thank you.

Comment: haha! glad i could help :)